# Use current time of the day as an integer in python

Tags: python, time, clock

I am looking to create an if then statement that involves the current time of the day. For example I want something like if it is past 2pm then do this function.

I have tried using the time module but I can't seem to find a way to get just the time of day without the extra stuff like the date. Any help?

Comment: You should always start by posting what you've tried that didn't work and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, and I think it'll be enough for you to get to the answer and use it how you need.

```
import time
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
print(time.strftime("I can format the date and time in many ways. Time is: %H:%M"))
```

Output (when I ran it):

```
2017-06-21 10:40
I can format the date and time in many ways. Time is: 10:40
```